# Explode prevsiouly rolled up data in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have data as follows:

```
Product        Quantity
A               3
B               2
```

This is data that as been previously rolled up at the product level. Assume there are only two columns as of now.

I want an output as follows:

```
Product      Quantity
A            1
A            1
A            1
B            1
B            1
```

Comment: Just curious, why would you want this?

Comment: ...and do you know in advance what the upper limit of Quantity might be?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a trick like this:

```
SELECT Product, 1 AS Quantity
FROM
  Products INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS q UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 3
  ) quantities
  ON Products.Quantity = quantities.q
```

of course, this query is limited to a quantity of 3, but you can add more quantities to your subquery if they are of a limited amount.

Comment: @Strawberry I think it's a trick because it's not a good use of sql...but without using some code, there's not much else to do :) but I'm also not native english speaker so maybe I'm misusing the word "trick" :)

Comment: Your use of English is just fine. But if this was a magic show, I would want a refund! ;-)